# Store date values in Google Datastore

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to store a date value in Google Datastore using the [Google API PHP Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) but the service replies always with an error:

Invalid value for: Invalid format: "2014-08-18 12:40:52" is malformed at " 12:40:52".

Here's the interesting section of the code I use:

```
function create_entity($name, $property, $data) {
    $entity = new Google_Service_Datastore_Entity();
    $entity->setKey(createKey($name));

    $string_prop = new Google_Service_Datastore_Property();
    $string_prop->setStringValue($data);
    $string_prop->setIndexed(false);

    $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $string_date = new Google_Service_Datastore_Property();
    $string_date->setDateTimeValue($time);
    $string_date->setIndexed(false);

    $property_map = [];
    $property_map[$property] = $string_prop;
    $property_map['date'] = $string_date;

    $entity->setProperties($property_map);

    return $entity;
}

function create_commit($name, $property, $data) {
    $entity = create_entity($name, $property, $data);

    $mutation = new Google_Service_Datastore_Mutation();
    $mutation->setUpsert([$entity]);

    $req = new Google_Service_Datastore_CommitRequest();
    $req->setMode('NON_TRANSACTIONAL');
    $req->setMutation($mutation);
    return $req;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Cloud Datastore docs](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities), the `dateTimeValue` property must be a string that is RFC 3339 formatted):

> `dateTimeValue`: string (RFC 3339 formatted, with milliseconds, for instance `2013-05-14T00:01:00.234Z`)

Comment: Thank you Patrick. I missed the documentation. I used date("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP"); and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have:

```
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Replace with:

```
$time = date(DATE_RFC3339);
```

This will give you the date time formatted to comply with RFC 3339 which is the format for the Google Cloud Datastore `dateTimeValue`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to store a datetime in local time? I tried storing  in iso 8601 format with timezones offset. It records the value as string type. When you create entity in the datastore UI you can store datetime in local time. Can you store datetime in local time using the datastore node.js module?